# Unable to change button text on click toggle JQUERY

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm new to JQUERY and I want to change the button text when user clicks on it from "Reservar" to "RESERVADO" and from "RESERVADO" to "Reservar" again, and so on (toggle).

But I can only change the button text once, and then it doesn't change anymore. Any help is appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rec").click(function() {
    if ($("#rec").text() === 'RESERVADO') {
      $("#rec").html("Reservar")
      $("#rec").css('color', 'blue');
      $("#6").appendTo($("#disponibles"));
    } else if ($("#rec").text() === 'Reservar') {
      $("#rec").html("RESERVADO")
      $("#rec").css('color', 'red');
      $("#6").appendTo($("#reservados"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="6" class="m-2 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl lg:flex lg:max-w-lg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="w-1/1 lg:w-1/2 rounded-l-2xl">
  <div class="p-6 bg-gray-50">
    <h2 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900">Recursividad y contingencia</h2>

    <p class="text-gray-600">Yuk Hui se aboca a esa tarea mediante una reconstrucción histórico-crítica del concepto de lo orgánico en filosofía, que aparece en la Crítica de la facultad de juzgar de Kant y plantea una ruptura respecto a la visión mecanicista del mundo para fundar
      un nuevo umbral del pensamiento.</p>

    <button id="rec" class="bg-transparent mt-5 hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded">
        Reservar
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are   `$("#disponibles")` and `$("#reservados")` elements ?

Comment: divs representing categories, books "disponibles" are available and "reservados" are reserved by the customer. if i click on the button "Reservar" the book will move to the "reservados" div, and if i click on "reservado", it will undo and go back to available (disponibles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your button markup results in whitespace in its text value, which causes the comparison to fail. Trim that away and your script works.

Other tips:

- Define constant values to reduce repeated selector processing.
- Chain methods for simpler code.
- Use a class or other abstract method to track state rather than text value. This is more robust as you can then change button text without breaking the script.
- Button text really shouldn't be used for feedback. It's nonsensical to use a button, which implies that it's available for an action, to report what's already been done. Instead, consider removing the button and showing a simple message.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const btnEl = $("#rec");
  const sixEl = $("#6")

  btnEl.click(function() {
    const btnText = btnEl.text().trim(); // remove leading and trailing whitespace

    if (btnText === 'RESERVADO') {
      btnEl.text("Reservar").css('color', 'blue');
      sixEl.appendTo($("#disponibles"));
    } else if (btnText === 'Reservar') {
      btnEl.text("RESERVADO").css('color', 'red');
      sixEl.appendTo($("#reservados"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="6" class="m-2 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl lg:flex lg:max-w-lg">
  <div class="p-6 bg-gray-50">
    <button id="rec" class="bg-transparent mt-5 hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded">
        Reservar
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you wrote your buttons tags there are spaces character before and after "Reservar" so just edit your button as following:

```
<button id="rec" class="bg-transparent mt-5 hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded">Reservar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simly use a [classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

and some CSS ( with `::before` )

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#rec").click(function()
    {
    if (this.classList.toggle('RESERVADO') )
      $("#6").appendTo($("#reservados"));
    else
      $("#6").appendTo($("#disponibles"));
    });
  });
```

```css
#rec::before {
  color   : blue;
  content : 'Reservar';
  }
#rec.RESERVADO::before {
  color   : red;
  content : 'RESERVADO';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="6" class="m-2 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl lg:flex lg:max-w-lg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="w-1/1 lg:w-1/2 rounded-l-2xl">
  <div class="p-6 bg-gray-50">
    <h2 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900">Recursividad y contingencia</h2>

    <p class="text-gray-600">Yuk Hui se aboca a esa tarea mediante una reconstrucción histórico-crítica del concepto de lo orgánico en filosofía, que aparece en la Crítica de la facultad de juzgar de Kant y plantea una ruptura respecto a la visión mecanicista del mundo para fundar
      un nuevo umbral del pensamiento.</p>

    <button id="rec" class="bg-transparent mt-5 hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, but this isn't very intuitive and (IMO) content shouldn't be stored in CSS.

Comment: @isherwood  it's debatable, changing the color and the text are both a stylistic issue here. if the text had been the same I would have used a `text-transform: uppercase;`